# Stuck at Jsoup.parse(html)

Tags: android-studio, jsoup

I am confused by this bug:
  I am sure that the String html is totally no problem, but it seems that the application is stuck at the method Jsoup.parse(html). Can anybody tell my why? It is so weird that I have tested the code on Eclipse and it worked fine, but when it comes to Android Studio, bug apppears.

```
String html = DataUtil.doGet(url);
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Comment: What is the error message exactly? Maybe that can help to figure it out.

Comment: There is no error message. But all the statements below the Jsoup.parse() can not be executed.

Comment: Do you use the same version of jsoup in both cases? Try to change version in studio.

Comment: Good point, I will try it. And anthor problem is that the html I fetched using Eclipse is totally different from the one I fetched using Android Studio. Probably this is another result of the diffrent version of jsoup.

Comment: Hi @Mindjet, i'm running into the very same problem. Do you have updates or tips three years later ?

Comment: For those like me who ran into the hang problem : upgrade Jsoup to 1.12.1-SHAPSHOT resolved the problem for me.